# Querying nested JSON structures in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I got the following format of JSON document with nested structures

```json
{
    "id": "p-1234-2132321-213213213-12312",
    "name": "athena to the rescue",
    "groups": [
        {
            "strategy_group": "anyOf",
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "strategy_conditions": "anyOf",
                    "entries": [
                        {
                            "c_key": "service",
                            "C_operation": "isOneOf",
                            "C_value": "mambo,bambo,jumbo"
                        },
                        {
                            "c_key": "hostname",
                            "C_operation": "is",
                            "C_value": "lols"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "tags": [
        "aaa",
        "bbb",
        "ccc"
    ]
}
```

I have created table in Athena to support it using the following

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS filters ( id string, name string, tags array<string>, groups array<struct<
    strategy_group:string,
    conditions:array<struct<
        strategy_conditions:string,
        entries: array<struct<
            c_key:string,
            c_operation:string,
            c_value:string
        >>
    >>
>> ) row format serde 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' location 's3://filterios/policies/';
```

My goal at the moment is to query based on the conditions entries columns as well. I have tried some queries however sql language is not my biggest trade ;)

I got at the moment to this query which gives me entries

```sql
select cnds.entries from 
filters,
UNNEST(filters.groups) AS t(grps),
UNNEST(grps.conditions) AS t(cnds)
```

However since this is complex array it gives me some headeache what would be the proper way to query.

Any hints appreciated!

thanks
R

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure whether I understood your query well. Look at this example below, maybe it will be useful to you.

```sql
select 
    id, 
    name, 
    tags,
    grps.strategy_group,
    cnds.strategy_conditions,
    enes.c_key,
    enes.c_operation, 
    enes.c_value 
from 
    filters,
    UNNEST(filters.groups) AS t(grps),
    UNNEST(grps.conditions) AS t(cnds),
    UNNEST(cnds.entries) AS t(enes)
where 
    enes.c_key='service'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example i recently worked with that may help:

My JSON:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
    "first": "raj",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-117.06861096, 32.57889962]
    },
    "properties": "someprop"
}] 
}
```

Created external table :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `jsondata`(
  `type` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `features` array<struct<type:string,geometry:struct<type:string,coordinates:array<string>>>> COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'paths'='features,type') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://vicinitycheck/rawData/jsondata/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='json')
```

Query data :

```
SELECT type AS TypeEvent,
     features[1].geometry.coordinates AS FeatherType
FROM test_vicinitycheck.jsondata
WHERE type = 'FeatureCollection'
```

test_vicinitycheck - Is my database name in Athena
jsondata - table name in Athena

I documented some examples on my blog if it helps:
http://weavetoconnect.com/aws-athena-and-nested-json/